# Retrieve and send data with mootools Request

Tags: php, json, mootools, request

I am retrieving a data with moo using Request and works fine , but at the same time I need to send some data to the same file I am getting request from ,

The working code is

```
     var myRequest =  new Request({
          url: 'json.php',
          onComplete: function (response) {
              var jresponse = JSON.decode(response);
              alert(jresponse.count)
          }
      }).get();
```

In my json.php  I have

```
echo '{"count":5, "times":1}';
```

That is ok and I get alerts for count and times ,

But the code in json.php needs to be refined and I need to check a file id which is stored in a tag data-fileid="123"

So I need to send  data-fileid="123" to json.php   and check condition before giving the

```
  echo '{"count":5, "times":1}';
```

I tried to do this at the end of my request

```
myRequest.send('fileid=' + el.get('data-fileid'));
```

but I don't know how to retrieve it or if it was sent to json.php at all.

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: The Request object has a `data` parameter: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is right: when you need to send data to the script at the server side, you use the method `send` of the class `Request`.

From the [documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Request/Request#Request%3asend), we can analyze this example:

```
var myRequest = new Request({
    url: 'http://localhost/some_url'
}).send('save=username&name=John');
```

when this gets executed, the script at `http://localhost/some_url` —if is PHP like yours—, will be able to access the variables:

```
$_REQUEST['save']     // with a value of "username"
$_REQUEST['name']     // with a value of "John"
```

so, in your example, `json.php` will have access to the variable:

```
$_REQUEST['fileid']
```

---

By the way, have you verified that the value given by:

```
el.get('data-fileid')
```

is the right one?

Comment: That is it , I am sending request and trying to get cookie or post or get , sorry , senior moment here. thank you much for explanation it makes much more sense now.